# Discordjs v12 args

Tags: discord.js, args

Can anyone help me with args? i have tested `.bet (number under 99)` but its wont reply me the message and same as `.bet (number more than 100)`

```
//My code
if (message.content.startsWith(".bet")) {
let bet = args.join(" ");
 // let bet = args[1]
  if (!args[0]) {
        return message.channel.send(`Woops, looks like you forgot to specify an amount to bet`)
    }
```

and this is the problems

```
//the problems

if (args[1] <= 99) {
  return
  message.channel.send("Sorry, You cannot bet under 99$")
  
}
if (args[2] >= 100) {
  return
  await db.add(`user.money_${message.author.id}`, -bet)

  message.channel.send("test")
}  

//
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code snippet you added in your post doesn't show the part where you define the `args` variable, so I created one here.

```js
const args = message.content.slice(".".length).trim().split(/ +/g).shift(); // split the message content on space and return the arguments

if (message.content.startsWith(".bet")) {
    if (!args[0]) { // if there's no argument
        return message.reply("Woops, looks like you forgot to specify an amount to bet!");
    }

    if (args[0] <= 99) { // if bet is equal/less than 99
        return message.reply("Sorry, you cannot bet under $99.");
    }

    if (args[0] >= 100) { // if bet is equal/greater than 100
        await db.add(`user.money_${message.author.id}`, -args[0]);
        return message.reply("Successfully added a bet.");
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks you so much